# How to convert from .srt to .ass with FFmpeg without decoding errors

Tags: ffmpeg, subtitles

When I try the following command with FFmpeg (v. git-2020-03-24-e5d25d1): `ffmpeg -i subs.srt subs.ass` ([subs.srt](http://www.mediafire.com/file/4bxvsrce14jbevn/subs.srt/file)), I get a bunch of the following errors:

```
[srt @ 0000028ea78fa780] Invalid UTF-8 in decoded subtitles text; maybe missing -sub_charenc option
Error while decoding stream #0:0: Invalid data found when processing input
```

and:

```
[ass @ 0000028ea78ffe40] ReadOrder gap found between 3 and 4
```

I found that my .srt file contains the following char: ë
I tried adding the flag `-sub_charenc UTF-8` as stated [here](https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/FFMPEG_An_Intermediate_Guide/subtitle_options#Set_Subtitles_Character_Encoding_Conversion) with no success.

How can I successfully convert .srt to .ass?

Comment: I can't duplicate the issue using e5d25d1. Please provide `subs.srt`.

Comment: I've added the file, it's a hyperlink at the top of my post.

Comment: Try `ffmpeg -sub_charenc ISO-8859-1 -i subs.srt subs.ass`

Comment: It worked, thank you very much. Take care yourself and others.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try:

```
ffmpeg -sub_charenc ISO-8859-1 -i subs.srt subs.ass
```

I used [`uchardet`](https://www.freedesktop.org/wiki/Software/uchardet/) to determine the character encoding:

```
$ uchardet subs.srt 
  ISO-8859-1
```